# Why do I get a KeyError when testing an S3 triggered Lambda that invalidates files in CloudFront?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a Python 3.7 Lambda function that invalidates CloudFront cache:

```py
from __future__ import print_function

import boto3
import time

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    for items in event["Records"]:
        path = "/" + items["s3"]["object"]["key"]
    print(path)
    client = boto3.client('cloudfront')
    invalidation = client.create_invalidation(DistributionId='distributionid__ID',
        InvalidationBatch={
            'Paths': {
                'Quantity': 1,
                'Items': [path]
        },
        'CallerReference': str(time.time())
    })
```

This is the attached IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my test JSON:

```
{
  "key1": "*"
}
```

Whenever I invoke my Lambda function, I get this error:

```
{'key 1': '*'}
[ERROR] KeyError: 'Records'
Traceback (most recent call last):
Version: $LATEST
    File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
        for items in event["Records"]:
```

Comment: Could you copy just the `Log Output` section into your question please, instead of adding a screenshot? ([Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4800344))

Comment: Right now i am providing the input myself.

Comment: Your test JSON doesn't have the `Records` key. That's what the error says. Please prepare a proper JSON according to your lambda code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is your input JSON - the code is expecting an Amazon S3 Event Notification.

Your input JSON does not have the [correct structure](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) as per docs, for an event message.

The Lambda errors as `for items in event["Records"]:` requires a `Records` property which is an array. You don't have this property at all in your JSON, resulting in the `KeyError` in the logs.

The below barebones test event should work, keeping in mind that you would never get `*` in real S3 event notifications.

```json
{"Records":[{"s3":{"object":{"key":"*"}}}]}
```

Comment: Now it says my distribution id is not found. `An error occurred (NoSuchDistribution) when calling the CreateInvalidation operation: The specified distribution does not exist.`.  I added this id from here. Is it the corrcet one ? or i am missing something. https://ibb.co/LSxzQb4

Comment: Looks like I needed to deploy before test. Thanks it worked awesome. Thank you for quick help this weekend.

Comment: @Santosh You're most welcome, enjoy using AWS :)